# External Hyperlink with a libgdx actor

Tags: facebook, url, libgdx, actor, stage

I have some Image actors on a stage that I want to redirect to Facebook, Instagram and a Fanpage when clicked. I searched online but can't find anything to help me do this. Can anyone give me some pointers on what I need to do.

```
    facebookLogo = new Image(skinMenu, "FacebookLogo");
    facebookLogo.setBounds(400, 20, 30, 30);
    facebookLogo.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //Go to Facebook page
            return true;
        }
    });
    layer.addActor(facebookLogo);

    instagramLogo = new Image(skinMenu, "InstagramLogo");
    instagramLogo.setBounds(440, 20, 30, 30);
    instagramLogo.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //Go to Instagram page
            return true;
        }
    });
    layer.addActor(instagramLogo);

    webLogo = new Image(skinMenu, "WebLogo");
    webLogo.setBounds(480, 20, 30, 25);
    webLogo.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //Go to website
            return true;
        }
    });
    layer.addActor(webLogo);
```

Answer (score 1):

After typing in "Gdx." and letting eclipse fill it in, I found the answer.

Gdx.net.openURI("http://

It uses the default browser to open the link.

You just need to stick that in the touchdown event of the InputListener

```
webLogo.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.net.openURI("http://<web page");
            return true;
        }
    });
    layer.addActor(webLogo);
```